# Trigger event on popover remote activation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have several popovers (pop1), (pop2), (pop3), that appear one after the other when the button "Next" is clicked on my webpage. So I can't actually access the popovers per say as they are remotely triggered.

Here is a jsbin demonstrating the process
http://jsbin.com/akutis/5/edit
(be sure to click on "run with JS")

I would like to trigger CSS actions, such as background-color change, when pop2 appears.

I tried using something like this, but it's all I can come up with... Any ideas how to do this with Jquery?

```
var number = 0;

$("#NextBtn").click(function() {
  if (currentPopover >= 0) {
    popovers[currentPopover].popover('hide');
  }

  currentPopover = currentPopover + 1;
  popovers[currentPopover].popover('show');

  number = number + 1;
  if (number=2) {
    $("#main_container").css("background-color", "red");
  }

});
```

Comment: take a look at this extended popover plugin https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover It has an `onShown` and `onHide` events that give you much more control over popovers on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add id="main_container" in your body tag and be carefull to your test : you wrote `number=2` insteadof `number==2`.

```
$("#NextBtn").click(function() {
  if (currentPopover >= 0) {
    popovers[currentPopover].popover('hide');
  }

  currentPopover = currentPopover + 1;
  popovers[currentPopover].popover('show');

  number = number + 1;
  if (number==2) {
    $("#main_container").css('background-color','red');
  } 

});
```